# Send POST data to PHP From Android App

Tags: java, php, android, post

I have spent hours trying to figure out why this isn't working. It matches many tutorials and examples online.

I'm trying to send the four variables as a `POST request` to a PHP page I have. The POST data never makes it to the mySQL database.

I have tested the PHP code separately and it works. I have also added internet permission to the manifest.

Java:

```
private class MyPost extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {
        Log.i("Webview", "Post Reequest Started");
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // replace with your url
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.notguiltyapp.com/commentform.php");

        // Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "name1"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", "comment"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Judge", "Judge1"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("add", "true"));

        // Encoding POST data
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log exception

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // making POST request.
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // write response to log
            Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Log exception

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['add'])){   
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $Judgename = $_POST['Judge'];
    $IP= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $Datestamp = date("F j, Y");
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];   
    if($name){      
        if($comment){
            mysql_connect("serverip","username","password");
            mysql_select_db("comments");
            $safename = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
            $safecomment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (id, name, comment, Judge, IP, Date) VALUES ('','$safename','$safecomment','$Judgename','$IP','$Datestamp')");
        }
        else
            echo "Empty Comment!";  
    }
    else
        echo "Empty Name!";
}

?>
```

Comment: I opened your link and all I saw was a `<` and believe it has something to do with `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void` which should probably read as `AsyncTask,Void, Void, Void` - The comma and the `<` on a keyboard are on the same key, so you might have pressed the shift key accidentally. Plus, without the ending `>` - However, I couldn't be 100% sure about this, yet it seems to have something to do with a `<` starting character.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, what you suggest would not be valid syntax. The angle brackets are a valid use of a generic type.

Comment: @hexafraction Ok. As per my edited comment above, it seems to have something to do with or near a `<` character. Might even be a PHP and/or SQL issue, but OP says it's ok.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, the `<` is being sent by the webserver. The code you're looking at that is in this post is client code, and the angle bracket is never transmitted (being a part of source code, and in fact being "erased" before runtime).

Comment: @hexafraction OK thanks. Do you see anything wrong with OP's code? If not, then it could be in fact with PHP and/or SQL code. I don't know this type of code, but I do know enough PHP/SQL.

Comment: I do not, but this code, being Java, is not PHP/SQL. To OP: Please try to send the request to a [Requestbin](http://requestb.in) to see what ends up actually being sent from the client.

Comment: I'll try requestbin. I've also posted the PHP code. I had an extra "<" in my php code but that didn't effect the code. I've since taken it out.

Comment: Do something like <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> and see the output

Comment: I added an echo for all POST data and it returns an empty array. So the problem has to be in either the encoding or the sending of the POST data. Any ideas?